# How to call non static method from main class

Tags: java, android

I just ran into this problem while coding android. If I have a non-static method (It has to be non-static for the code inside to work) in my main class, how am i supposed to call it from within another class, because obviously I can't create another instance of my main class without starting a new instance of the program?

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
public static String starttime = "";
public static String startdate = "";
public static String endtime = "";
public static String enddate = "";
public static boolean start = false;
}

public void setDateText() {
    EditText TextStart = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_start);
    TextStart.setText(startdate + " at " + starttime, TextView.BufferType.NORMAL);
    EditText TextEnd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_end);
    TextEnd.setText(enddate + " at " + endtime, TextView.BufferType.NORMAL);
}
```

Any help on how to call the `setDateText()` method from another class?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `setDateText` outside the `MainActivity` class?

Comment: is your another class a activity class?

Comment: setDateText() must be in some class...is it supposed to be in MainActivity?

Comment: Pass on Instance of other class to this class, and use that instance to call the non-static method.

Comment: Sorry, yes setDateText is in the MainActivity class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you can't call a non static method from a static type, so you would do:

```
MainActivity m = new MainActivity(); // No constructor needed in class def.

m.setDateText();
```

But, when the program starts, you're not giving your JVM anything to call at the start, so you need to add:

```
  @Override
//the function called when activity is created
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //call the create fct. Of the base class
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //load the layout specified in the layout.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    MainActivity m = new MainActivity();

    m.setDateText();
}
```

This will be called when the activity is created.

Go to [Android - A beginner's guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/102065/Android-A-beginner-s-guide) for more information.

Also watch your syntax, your method def is outside of your class def.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which other class is trying to access the `MainActivity` instance, you will need to pass a reference of this instance to your other objects, probably by passing `this` into a constructor or method.

For example

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    public void someMethod() {
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass(this); // pass this for callbacks
        // ~ more
    }
}
```

where `SomeClass` is a class where you need to call the `MainActivity`'s `setDateText` method.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand the need for you to call the function from another activity. Your main activity is anyway not on the foreground, so if you call this function from there, date will not be shown. Once you finish the 2nd activity and you will be back to MainActivity, then only you need this function to be called.

If that is so, then you can use startActivityForResult() to start 2nd activity, and then pass the date information back to MainActivity through onActivityResult(). You can call this function in MainActivity itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to invoke `setDate()` at the activity's launch, you can pass the date in the `Intent` when you launch the activity and pull the date in `MainActivity`'s `onCreate` method.

If you have to invoke setDate() at a different time other than launch, you can send a broadcast from other activity/component and make `MainActivity` listen to the `Broadcast` and pull the date from the intent's data.